# Unknown column xxx in 'field list' when joining tables (MySQL, MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, sql

The Homework question is: Write a SQL query to list the names of all students enrolled in Web and Database Computing.
There are three tables here:[**enrolments**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMtr5.png) 
  [**students**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBkKZ.png)   [**subjects**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VRMK.png) These 3 tables are in the same database called **Enrolment**.

I have tried to combine three tables together and print out the whole table, it works!

```
 MariaDB [enrolment]> SELECT *
    -> FROM students st
    -> JOIN enrolments en
    -> ON st.student_id=en.student_id
    -> JOIN subjects su
    -> ON en.subject_code = su.subject_code
    -> WHERE su.name='Web and Database Computing';
```

However, I only want to print out the names of all students enrolled in Web and Database Computing, so I change the code:

```
MariaDB [enrolment]> SELECT name FROM students st
    -> JOIN enrolments en
    -> ON st.student_id=en.student_id
    -> JOIN subjects su
    -> ON en.subject_code = su.subject_code
    -> WHERE su.name='Web and Database Computing';
```

It gives me the error

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'students.name' in 'field list'

Comment: just to be sure that it is not an alias issue, can you try st.name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace name to st.name because you given the alias students table as st
name replace by st.name  (because in students table name field available as well as subjects table available name you can give compulsory alias dot column name )
 following as below...

```
 SELECT st.name
         FROM students st
         JOIN enrolments en
         ON st.student_id=en.student_id
         JOIN subjects su
         ON en.subject_code = su.subject_code
         WHERE su.name='Web and Database Computing';
```

Comment: @Yinhao did you get solution? or did my solution is work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Even though MySQL didn't throw an ambiguity error, Name seems to be an ambiguous column here, as it is present in both Subjects and Students. So, can you please try:

`st.name` instead of `name`?